# whether gremlin needs to store all data in java?

Tags: java, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

gremlin is a graph query language developed by stephen mallette, etc.
[apache tinkerpop](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin).

I looked through its open source and found it provide API for developers(vendors). And I have a question whether I can use an OLTP or OLAP written in other languages, not java, as my graph system.

I guess it maybe difficult because I think the java class containing data like edges, vertexes and their properties need to be calculated in GraphProgram or VertexProgram process in gremlin. If I want to use gremlin to make a query for my graph, I have to copy one complete data in java and implement the necessary function to override the provided interface. Is that right? Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just talking about writing queries, you can develop both OLTP and OLAP based traversals in any of the languages that TinkerPop supports at this time: JVM-based (Java, Groovy, Scala, Clojure, etc), JavaScript, Python or .NET. With non-JVM languages however you do need an instance of [Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-server) running or you need to use a TinkerPop implementation that exposes the Gremlin Server protocol, like DSE Graph, CosmosDB, Amazon Neptune, JanusGraph on Compose from IBM, etc.

If however you intend to write your own `VertexProgram` for OLAP, then you will need to use a JVM language to do that. You couldn't, for example, write a `VertexProgram` in Python.

Comment: Wow! it's lucky to get answer so quickly. Perhaps I still have some question to ask. In fact, I want to know whether the vendor’s graph database or graph processor must be written in Java. I think gremlin-python or gremlin-javascript can provide users a method to write traversals by using python or javascript. They are used for developing application on gremlin and not the driver of database or processor which provides API for gremlin.

Comment: right - graph implementations (like `VertexProgram` implementations) must be written in Java (or JVM compatible language I suppose). maybe someday we'll have full Gremlin Virtual Machines in every language to allow that, but for now we only have the JVM.

Comment: I got it. thanks a lot. btw. gremlin is really a fantastic project